# stringsplit output as new colnames

Tags: r

I would like to create new colnames for my dataframe `MirAligner` consisting of the part before the first `_` in the original colnames. This is what I tried:

```
unlist(strsplit(as.character(colnames(MirAligner)),'_',fixed=TRUE))
```

Column names

```
head(colnames(MirAligner))
[1] "na-008_S52_L003_R1_001.mir.fa.gz"  "na-014_S99_L005_R1_001.mir.fa.gz" "na015_S114_L005_R1_001.mir.fa.gz" [4] "na-015_S50_L003_R1_001.mir.fa.gz"  "na-018_S147_L007_R1_001.mir.fa.gz" "na020_S162_L007_R1_001.mir.fa.gz"
```

Expected output:

```
na-008 na-014 na015
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
sub('_.*', '', str1)
#[1] "na-014" "na015"  "na-015" "na-018" "na020"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("na-014_S99_L005_R1_001.mir.fa.gz", 
          "na015_S114_L005_R1_001.mir.fa.gz", 
          "na-015_S50_L003_R1_001.mir.fa.gz",  
          "na-018_S147_L007_R1_001.mir.fa.gz", 
          "na020_S162_L007_R1_001.mir.fa.gz")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
gsub("^(.*?)_.*", "\\1", try5)
#[1] "na-008" "na-014" "na015"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using *strsplit* within *sapply*:

```
#myColNames <- colnames(MirAligner)
myColNames <- c("na-008_S52_L003_R1_001.mir.fa.gz", "na-014_S99_L005_R1_001.mir.fa.gz")

sapply(strsplit(myColNames, "_", fixed = TRUE), "[[", 1)
#output
# [1] "na-008" "na-014"
```

Or using *read.table*:

```
read.table(text = myColNames, sep = "_", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[, "V1"]
```